# Submit form if ajax validator returns true using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am not sure where I'm going wrong. The idea is that before the form is submitted, one of the input fields is sent to a server-side validator via ajax. If the response is 1, the input is valid and the form should be submitted. If the response is 0, the form should not be submitted. The issue is that I can't figure out how to set a variable within the ajax request function that will prevent the form from being submitted. This is what I have:

```
$("#form").submit(function() {
    var valid= false;
    var input = $("#input").val();
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "validator.php",
       data: "input=" + input,
       success: function(msg){
            valid = (msg == 1) ? true : false;
            if(!valid) {
                $("#valid_input").html("Please enter valid info");
            } else {
                $("#valid_input").html("");
            }
       }
     });
    return valid;
 });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the `$.ajax` request is asynchronous and takes a while to complete. Therefore the function carries on and returns false before the success function is event executed.

To solve this you could add `async: false` to you settings for the AJAX call, but this would suspend execution until the AJAX call returns.

Another solution would be to create a hidden input in the form called `valid`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="valid" value="false" />
```

Then within the submit function but before the ajax call create a reference to the from `var $form = $(this)`. Then if the AJAX call returns valid change the value of this hidden input, and submit the form again:

```
$('input[name="valid"]').val('true');
$form.submit();
```

And then at the end of the submit function only return false if the value of the hidden input is true:

```
if ($('input[name="valid"]').val() == 'false') {
    $.ajax({ ... }); // changes the value of the hidden input from false to true
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Suspending execution until the HTTP response arrives is a **bad** thing, don't do that.

Comment: Yer don't use the `async: false` solution, it simply explains the situation you have. See my modified answer for a more sensible solution.

Comment: Okay, I went with the hidden variable flag, good call. Thanks!

Comment: Hey all. I'm loading a signup page using fancybox plugin. I'm placing #form.submit() within ajax success function. It's reloading the page and displaying the empty form, but on a separate page (not within the fancybox). When I view source, it doesnt have valid as "false". Lastly, what do I put into $.ajax({...})?? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The success function runs **when the HTTP response arrives** so `valid` will **always** be false.

Call the form's `.submit()` method if it is valid (and make sure you don't have a form control with the name or id *submit* as that will clobber the method).

Comment: The problem with that (as my code is currently set up) is that it's the form submit that is the initial trigger. So when I tried calling the form's .submit() within the ajax, it did an infinite loop.

Comment: The problem here is that the event handler will call this function again and then make the AJAX call again, infinity.

Comment: Calling a form's `submit()` method should not trigger the `submit` event handler. Are you calling a jQuery submit method instead of a DOM submit method? That might behave differently.

Comment: Would that look like `$('form#form_id').context.submit()`?

Comment: No, `context` returns any DOM nodes passed. You are passing a selector there. `jQuery('#form_id')[0].submit()` should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

this is assuming that you have loaded the ajax validate plugin and the ajax form plugin,
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

the example below will make all forms with class "ajaxForm" validate and then if valid submit via ajax...

```
$( document ).ready( function(){setupForms();} );

function setupForms(){

    var ajaxOptions = { beforeSubmit:checkForm,
                        success:function(){
                               // the ajax was successful
                       }
                      };

    $( '.ajaxForm' ).ajaxForm( ajaxOptions );   
    $( '.ajaxForm' ).validate();
}

function checkForm(data,form){
    var valid = $(form).valid();
    return valid;
}
```