# If AJAX returns true, do something

Tags: jquery, css, json, ajax, get

I am using an AJAX call to recieve some data from PHP file in a JSON format and regarding if part of that data is true, I want to change the color of my element.

I've tried doing it like it says here( `async:false` ):
[Submit form if ajax validator returns true using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597675/submit-form-if-ajax-validator-returns-true-using-jquery)

But it doesen't work as it should.

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: 'preveri.php',
  data: {
    "row": row, 
    "col": col
  },
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  success: function( data ){
    var jsonstuff = data;
    var trys = data.trys[0];
    var result = data.result[0];
    var finished = data.finished[0];

    if (result == "true") {
      $(this).attr("style", "background-color: green");
    } else {
      $(this).attr("style", "background-color: red");
    }
  }
});
```

I have tried using this before the AJAX call, so it definitely works:

```
$(this).attr("style", "background-color:red");
```

I have also tried replacing `this` with an ID of the element and it also didn't work. I have also tried to make the `result` as a global variable and than call the if - else after the ajax.

The JSON data in PHP is:

```
    $data = array();
    $data['result'] = array($Result);
    $data['trys'] = array($trys);
    $data['finished'] = array($finished);
    $myJSON =  json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Firstly, remove `async: false`. It's really bad practice to the point that the browser will put warnings in the console about its use. Secondly, what is the value of `data` (and therefore `result`) - assuming the AJAX call is even successful. Try also checking the console for errors.

Comment: What's the JSON data?

Comment: `this` isn't what you think it is...

Comment: Try this -  $("#your elementid").style("bgcolor", "#FF0000");//red

Comment: @user557657 Like I said, if I use the css changing before the ajax, it works prfectly.

Comment: @tymeJV I wrote that I tried replacing this with an ID, but it also didn't work.

Comment: you do echo $MyJSON before php exits? And what is result?

Comment: @Lexib0y If I write var trys, finished and result in console (jquery) It looks fine. (For example: true, 1 and false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing that you have to defines you $(this) golbal and try below code

```
var this_var =$(this);
$.ajax({ 
url: 'preveri.php',
data: {"row": row,"col": col},
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'json',
success: function( data ){
var jsonstuff = data;
var trys = data.trys[0];
var result = data.result[0];
var finished = data.finished[0];
 if (result == "true") {this_var.css("background-color","green");} else {this_var.css("background-color","red");}}});
```

Comment: This really works, I guess there was some problem with "this". Thank you, I hope some other people can learn from this as well. .)

Comment: I did, but I don't have enough score to count yet.